# Python - Thread copied duplicate

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading

Am trying to do multithreading in my python app. I got main thread which creates sub-threads. However, for testing am only using 1 thread. The task that the thread must do is collect data and then store it in DB. But, I can see it stores it twice, after debugging I found that I get 2 threads instead of 1.

**main program :**

```
app = webApp.app

def main_program():
    sleep(3)
    while True:
        Sensor.sensors.items()


def start_webApp():
    bottle.run(app=app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, reloader=True, debug=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_webApp).start()
    s1_thread = threading.Thread(target=sensor_thread.start_sensor_reading, args=(14, SL.bedroom_1,), name="Sensor_1")
    s1_thread.start()
    main_program()
```

**thread file**

```
def start_sensor_reading(sensor_pin, sensor_location):
    sleep(3)
    global sensor, current, pulses, sensor_status
    sensor = DigitalInputDevice(sensor_pin)
    current = WFS.isIdle
    pulses = 0
    valve_open_time = 0
    valve_close_time = 0
    Sensor.sensors[sensor_location] = False
    doc_ref = db.collection(sensor_location.value).document()
    while True:
        if current == WFS.isIdle:
            print("idle")
        if sensor.value == 1:
            print("S IS OPENED")
            current = WFS.isOpened
            if pulses == 0:
                valve_open_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        if current == WFS.isOpened:
            m, s = get_time_diff(valve_open_time)
            if s > 30:
                Sensor.sensors[sensor_location] = True
            while sensor.value == 1:
                print("S IS OPENED - Counting pulses")
                pulses += sensor.value
            current = WFS.isNoisy
        if current == WFS.isNoisy:
            print("S IN NOISE")
            valve_close_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            while sensor.value == 0:
                print("S IN NOISE - checking if will close")
                minutes, seconds = get_time_diff(valve_close_time)
                if seconds > 3:
                    current = WFS.isClosed
                    break
        if current == WFS.isClosed:
            current = WFS.isIdle
            sleep(10) <<< HERE IS THE PROBLEM - I do sleep 10 secs to see how many times it prints <<<<<<
            print("S IS CLOSED - SAVING IN DB - SENSOR PIN : " + str(sensor_pin))
            sleep(10)
            m, s = get_time_diff(valve_open_time)
            duration = str(m) + ":" + str(s)
            liters = pulses / 450
            doc_ref.set({
                'Liters': liters,
                'Started_At': valve_open_time,
                'Stopped_At': valve_close_time,
                'Duration': duration
            })
            pulses = 0
```

**console output**

```
S IN NOISE - checking if will close
S IN NOISE - checking if will close
S IS CLOSED - SAVING IN DB - SENSOR PIN : 14
S IS CLOSED - SAVING IN DB - SENSOR PIN : 14
idle
idle
idle
idle
```

As you can see I must get **IS CLOSED** printed once but it appears twice

Regards

Comment: As an aside, `app_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_webApp).start()`  - `start()` returns `None`, not the thread. If you want to keep a reference to the thread, you need to `app_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_webApp);app_thread.start()`.

Comment: thank you for your comment, will keep it in mind

Comment: `current` is initialized to `WFS.isIdle`, and the first branch of the `if` checks for that, so the first line of output should be `idle`... please post complete, executable code.

Comment: you are correct the first line of output should be idle but am making it short. because I cannot paste all of out put lines

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was flask thread cousing the coping of the threads so I removed it then evrything was working fine.